# iOS UIDatePicker's date and now date early 8 hours

Tags: ios, swift, timezone, uidatepicker

There are my codes, I have dealt with the time zone, and now the time from the datepicker is correct, but the time displayed on the datepicker is still wrong, and the current time obtained by using `Date()` is also wrong.

```
 @IBAction func dateChanged(_ datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
            let timeZone = NSTimeZone.system
            let interval = timeZone.secondsFromGMT(for: datePicker.date)

            let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .timeZone], from: datePicker.date.addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(interval)))
            remindDate = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)!

            print("+++++++++++++DatePicker: \(datePicker.date)++++++++++++++Date: \(remindDate)++++++++++++++Now: \(Date())+++++++++++++")

            updateDateDetial(remindDate)

        }
```

Here is the result of the `print()`:

> +++++++++++++DatePicker: 2018-05-25 02:44:33 +0000++++++++++++++Date: 2018-05-25 10:44:00 +0000++++++++++++++Now: 2018-05-24 00:44:38
>   +0000+++++++++++++

The time I chose from datepicker is 2018-05-25 10:44. The time now should be 2018-05-24 8:44:38. However, there is still a gap with the time in the program.

Comment: None of the dates are "wrong" until you start manipulating them in unncecessry ways. The date/time shown on the picker is in your local timezone.  If you just print the date object from the picker, it is shown in UTC, so there will be a difference which is equal to the difference between your local time zone and utc, but the two times represent the same *point in time*

Comment: See the [following article](http://www.maddysoft.com/articles/dates.html) to help understand `Date` better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code that adds a time interval offset from GMT is wrong. Don't do that.

The problem you are facing is that dates are displayed in GMT (UTC) by default. You can use the DateFormatter class method localizedDate to give you a date string in the current locale.

```
let datePickerDateString = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: datePicker.date,
  dateStyle: .medium,
  timeStyle, .medium)
let remindDateString = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: remindDate,
  dateStyle: .medium,
  timeStyle, .medium)
let nowString = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(),
  dateStyle: .medium,
  timeStyle, .medium)
print("+++++++++++++DatePicker: \(datePickerDateString)++++++++++++++Date: \(remindDateString)++++++++++++++Now: \(nowString)+++++++++++++")
```

I created a simple extension to the Date class that makes this much easier to do:

```
extension Date {
    func localString(dateStyle: DateFormatter.Style = .medium, timeStyle: DateFormatter.Style = .medium) -> String {
        return DateFormatter.localizedString(from: self, dateStyle: dateStyle, timeStyle: timeStyle)
    }
}
```

That collapses your code down to:

```
        print("+++++++++++++DatePicker: \(datePicker.date.localString())" + 
              "++++++++++++++Date: \(remindDate.localString())" + 
              "++++++++++++++Now: \(Date().localString())+++++++++++++")
```

### EDIT

If you're installing the date picker's date into a label that code might look like this (using the `Date` extension above)

```
myLabel.text = datePicker.date.localString()
```

(Although note that you should really save the date into an instance variable when the user changes it rather than fetching it from the date picker. Saving model data in view objects is a code smell.)

Comment: The date I got from datepicker is wrong, but it is correct that I display the datepicker's date on the label. If I change this, then the date I get from datepicker is correct, but the datepicker's date is It is wrong to show on the label.

Comment: So edit your question to show the (incorrect) code that puts the datePicker's date into the label. Mucking with interval offsets to UTC is wrong. Don't do that.